# Log4j2 logger isn't writing in log file

Tags: java, logging, log4j2, jboss7.x

I'm trying to configure Log4j2 for my application. I want to define two appenders, one for console and another for the log file, both in `INFO` level.

I'm using JBoss EAP 7.4 to deploy my application, I've excluded the JBoss logging subsystem already.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-deployment-structure xmlns="urn:jboss:deployment-structure:1.2">
    <deployment>
        <exclude-subsystems>
            <subsystem name="logging" />
        </exclude-subsystems>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

This is my log4j2.xml configuration file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="WARN">
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%m%n" />
        </Console>
        <File name="File" fileName="${jboss.server.log.dir}/srcu/srcu.log">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%m%n" />
        </File>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Root level="info">
            <AppenderRef ref="Console" />
            <AppenderRef ref="File" />
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

So far it's only showing to the console, but to the log file it's not writing anything. This is how I'm using the `Logger` in my app:

```
public class ExampleServiceImpl implements ExampleService {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LogManager.getRootLogger();

    @GET
    @Path("/getListData")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Override
    public ExampleResp getListData() {
        LOGGER.info("Inside of getListData method");
        ExampleDAOImpl exampleDAOImpl = new ExampleDAOImpl();
        ExampleResp resp = new ExampleResp();
        resp.setListData(exampleDAOImpl.getData());
        return resp;
    }

}
```

Comment: Is the file itself created?